# How to secure Restful Service (SSB exposed as service) running on JBossAS7?

Tags: security, jax-rs, resteasy, jboss7.x, ws-security

Context:
I am running my application on JBoss AS7 community version.
I am using Java API for JaxRS from jboss. (Not sure if it same as RestEasy?!) Here is my maven dependency

```
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
```

I am using a JaxRSActivator to enable JAX-RS in the application, as shown below. In my understanding this replaces the need to have servlet mapping inside web.xml

```
    @ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
   /* class body intentionally left blank */
}
```

I have created an EJB (SSB) and exposed it as a Restful service as shown below"

```
@Path("/Items")
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class ItemMgmtServiceBean {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id:[0-9][0-9]*}")
    @Produces("text/xml")
    public Item findItem(@PathParam("id")long itemId)
```

The REST service above runs perfectly on JBoss AS7. Please note that so far I did not have to use web.xml.

Now I want to secure this service. I want to use programmatic security inside this service to find the principal name (as per my business logic).

RestEasy documentation says that I should not switch on the context-param for EJBs.

```
 <context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

However it does not explain what I should use in web.xml or if I need to use web.xml at all for EJB based restful services.

Questions:

I want to use digest authentication. What steps do I need to take to enable this? .

Do I need to add a web.xml or can I change `JaxRSActivator` to enable security? 
If I need web.xml should I remove `JaxRSActivator`?
What should I configure in the web.xml?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Securing_JAX-RS_and_RESTeasy.html

Resteasy JAX-RS supports the @RolesAllowed, @PermitAll and @DenyAll annotations on JAX-RS methods. By default though, Resteasy does not recognize these annotations. You have to configure Resteasy to turn on role-based security by setting a context parameter. NOTE!!! Do not turn on this switch if you are using EJBs. The EJB container will provide this functionality instead of Resteasy.

Comment: I read this note in RESTEasy documentation. In spite of adding @RolesAllowed, it does not work. Also did you see the note on not to use the context parameter when you are using EJBs. There is no detailed example of how this works. Can you provide some code samples to help?